# Seaborn disable plot

Tags: python, wxpython, seaborn

I have a seaborn barplot embedded in a WxPython panel, like this:

[image]

The bar plot is drawn when the (big) button is clicked. This is what I made to accomplish it:

```
class SamplePanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.figure = Figure()
        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)

        self.x = np.array(list('XYZV'))
        self.y = np.array([200,400,300,20])

        self.ax.set_ylabel("Sample numbers")        

        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
        self.button = wx.Button(self, label="Plot data", pos=(100,15))
        self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButtonClick)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.GROW)
        self.sizer.Add(self.button, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.GROW)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.Fit()

    def OnButtonClick(self,event):
        sns.barplot(self.x, self.y, palette="BuGn_d", ax=self.ax)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = wx.Frame(None, title='Sample bar plot')
    panel = SamplePanel(frame)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I have two questions:

- How can I disable/draw the plot when I click the button? That is, if I click the button then the plot appears. If I click again the plot disappears and I get back to an empty original view, like this:
  [image]

  - Also, the plot only changes when I maximize the window, how can I change it to be immediate, as soon as I click the button?

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have helped a lot if you had posted a small runnable example. Fortunately, Google helped me figure out what all was needed. Basically you need to set some kind of variable to keep track of if you've clicked the button or not. Or you could use a `wx.ToggleButton` instead of a regular `wx.Button`.

To get the graph to display without resizing the frame, you just need to call `self.Layout()`.

To clear the figure, you'll need to do something like `self.ax.cla()` or `self.ax.clear()`. Here's a full example that worked for me:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import wx

from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class SamplePanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.toggled = False
        self.figure = Figure()
        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)

        self.x = np.array(list('XYZV'))
        self.y = np.array([200,400,300,20])

        self.ax.set_ylabel("Sample numbers")

        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
        self.button = wx.Button(self, label="Plot data", pos=(100,15))
        self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButtonClick)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.GROW)
        self.sizer.Add(self.button, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.GROW)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.Fit()

    def OnButtonClick(self, event):
        if not self.toggled:
            sns.barplot(self.x, self.y, palette="BuGn_d", ax=self.ax)
            self.toggled = True
        else:
            self.ax.cla()
            self.toggled = False
        self.Layout()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = wx.Frame(None, title='Sample bar plot', size=(800,600))
    panel = SamplePanel(frame)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Also note that `wx.PySimpleApp` is deprecated. I swapped it out for the recommended method of creating an app object.